# Scala regex pattern matching doesn't work

Tags: regex, scala, pattern-matching

```
val login = "login user=(.*), token=(.*)".r

"login user=SapHana_dummy token=dummy" match {
  case login(user, token) =>
    println("success")
}
```

This code always throws MatchError. Instead of printing "success" as intended. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your pattern expects a comma, here:

```
login user=(.*), token=(.*)
               ^
```

Which is not in the input text.

Also, to minimize backtracking, I'd use an ungreedy quantifier here:

```
login user=(.*?) token=(.*)
```